# How can i see how often my for loop did "++" to get the right value?

Tags: c#, loops

I wanna see how often that loop added B++ to get on that result. (Putting B into that {0} doesn't work...

```
int firsthousecase1 = 20;
int thirdhousecase1 = 40;

for (int B = 0; B != firsthousecase1; B++)
            {
                value += 1;
                for (; B != thirdhousecase1; B++)
                {
                    value += 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Case #{0}: {1}",); //Case #{0} should show me how many trys the console did to get the value from "value". 
                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can always use the debugger and put a breakpoint and step through each iteration of your loop and watch the values change yourself.

Comment: Given that B++ adds 1 each time, and B starts at 0, the number times we must do `++` to reach 20, is 20.. The number of additions to reach 40 is 40.. The general formula for the number of tiems you must increment a number by 1 to reach a target is `targetNumber - startingNumber`. Am I missing something?

Comment: As an aside, this is odd code, but a useful lesson: Avoid using `!=`  to limit actions in a loop; use something like `<` instead, for the simple reason that if you somehow miss the value you're waiting to `!=` with, you could end up running a lot longer than expected. Here B is 0, checked to be not equal to 20 (true), the loop starts, then another loop starts that would, if the `return` statement were not there, take B up to 40. That inner loop would then stop, the outer loop would increment B to 41, and then the inner loop would run again, this time taking B into billions..

Comment: If you use `<` then even if you miss your target, the loop will stop. Suppose in the sense of a timer, you have a thread that wakes up every second and checks the time. If you want the alarm at 9am, and you pin your hopes on the thread waking up at 8:59:58.. 8:59:59.. You might get a surprise if some sudden go-slow makes your thread sleep for 2 seconds, and only wake at 9:00:01. If you were waiting for `== 9:00:00` you'll sleep for another day before your chance comes again. If you were using `<` to "sleep until it's 9 or after" then your alarm would sound, albeit a second late, at 9:00:01

Comment: Using range checking `<` etc can be even more important with floating point numbers, as representations can be imprecise. And to answer the question *How can i see how often my for loop did "++" to get the right value?* - the code as presented never increments B; it `return`s before it gets a chance to. The 3 statements in a for are `for(do_once_before_loop; check_before_every_loop_and_only_loop_if_true; do_after_every_loop)` - this code never finishes either loop body, so never hits the do_after_every_loop bit